# Proof about isometries, symmetry and reversing orientation.

Tags: proof-writing, euclidean-geometry

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is an isometry of the reals. Prove that $f$ is a symmetry around a point if and only if $f$ reverses orientation of $\mathbb{R}$.

The orientation of $\mathbb{R}$ is the same as its order.

**Part 1:** The assumption is $f$ is a symmetry and we want to conclude it reverses the order.

**Part 2:** The assumption is $f$ is an isometry reversing the order and we want to conclude $f$ is a symmetry.

I'm not even sure how to begin this proof, much less how to do the rest of it.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you're not sure how to begin, begin by writing down (1) what it means for $f$ to be an isometry of $\Bbb R$, and (2) what it means for $f$ to be a symmetry around a point.

Answer (score 1):

Isometry of the reals means it preserves distances, so the distance from $x$ to $0$ is the same as from $f(x)$ to $f(0)$, or $|f(x)-f(0)|=|x-0|$. So $f(x)=f(0)\pm x$, and you have to pick $-$ if $f$ reverses the orientation of $\mathbb{R}$.

Now both parts get solved if you show that for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$ the map $f(x)=a-x$ is a symmetry around a point (hint: find which point stays fixed) and an isometry.